# Parse phone numbers from a pdf file

Tags: pdf, groovy

I want to read a `pdf` file and store phone numbers in the database. Is there any way to read pdf files using `groovy`?

Comment: I up-voted it.  It is unfair to down-vote this question with no explanation whatsoever.  Hunting Java libraries is challenging to beginners, and you just spitting in the face of someone that needs help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Apache PDFBox, a Java library.

http://pdfbox.apache.org/